# Передача данных sql в письмо phpmailer

Tags: javascript, php, sql, get, phpmailer

В php и js я совсем новичок и не могу понять как мне передать данные из базы данных в письмо, отправленное через phpmailer. Данные из базы я беру, отсортировывая через get запрос конкретной страницы.

script.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);

    async function formSend(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let error = formValidate(form);

        let formData = new FormData(form);

        if (error === 0) {
            form.classList.add('_sending');
            let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                let result = await response.json();
                alert(result.message);
                form.reset();
                form.classList.remove('_sending');
            }
            else {
                alert("Ошибка2");
                form.classList.remove('_sending');
            }
        }
        else {
            alert ("ошибка1");
        }
    }

    function formValidate(form) {
        let error = 0;
        let formReq = document.querySelectorAll('._req');

        for (let index = 0; index < formReq.length; index++) {
            const input = formReq[index];
            formRemoveError(input);

            if(input.classList.contains('_email')){
                if(emailTest(input)){
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            }
            else if(input.getAttribute("type") === "checkbox" && input.checked == false) {
                formAddError(input);
                error++;
            }
            else {
                if (input.value === '') {
                    formAddError(input);
                    error++;
                }
            }
        }
        return error;
    }

    function formAddError(input) {
        input.parentElement.classList.add('_error');
        input.classList.add('_error');
    }
    function formRemoveError(input) {
        input.parentElement.classList.remove('_error');
        input.classList.remove('_error');
    }

    function emailTest(input) {
        return !/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,8})+$/.test(input.value);
    }
});
```

sendmail.php:

```
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
   require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->IsHTML(true);

   $mail->setFrom('@gmail.com');
   $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
   $id = $_GET["id"]; 
   $category = $_GET["category"];
   $singles = get_singles_by_category_and_id($id, $category);
   foreach ($singles as $single) {
       $mail->Subject = 'Title ' $single["title"];
   }
   
   $mail->Body = '<h1>Title</h1>';

   if(trim(!empty($_POST['surname']))) {
       $mail->Body.='<p><strong>Surname:</strong> '.$_POST['surname'].'</p>';
   }
   if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))) {
       $mail->Body.='<p><strong>Name:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>';
   }

   if (!$mail->send()) {
       $message = 'Ошибка';
   }
   else {
       $message = 'Данные отправлены!';
   }

   $response = ['message' => $message];

   header('Content-type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: вы же добавляете в тему письма данные    $singles = get_singles_by_category_and_id($id, $category); foreach ($singles as $single) ... также можно добавить все что угодно в Body письма

Comment: @Aleksey Vaganov Благодарю! Все заработало! Вы гений!